# multiple ejb injections which implement the same interface

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb

i am very new to this ejb stuff. is there any possibility that in a single file i can have multiple injections based on some criteria.

for eg

```
public interface common(){
   public void sayhello();
    }

  beanA
     implements common()

  beanB
       implements common()
```

both are stateless beans

now i have a client which needs to trigger hello method based on some criteria. for eg. say based on console input if string contains A then beanA should be injected otherwise beanB. 
Is there any possibility? and again my next question is , can i say this dynamic injection is not managed by container? if so how can i let container take the control? i need a sample code or atleast any tutorial ref.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just so I understand your use-case, if both beans are stateless and implement a common interface, what does it matter which one is used?

Comment: they just have adfferent implementatipns

Comment: and that the client will a single interface exposed...

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not really possible.  You might be able to get close with a custom CDI scope that uses a thread local or session attribute, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Instead, just inject a reference to both EJBs, and select the one to use as needed:

```
@EJB(beanName="BeanA")
Common beanA;
@EJB(beanName="BeanB")
Common beanB;

private Common getCommon(String input) {
    return isBeanAInput(input) ? beanA : beanB;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bkail....So in this case, there will be redundant object created, in this case, will it be possible that container will remove the object?

Comment: There will be a redundant *proxy* object created, but the actual stateless instance will not allocated (and injected, and PostConstruct'ed, etc.) until a method is called on the proxy.

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this:

```
public interfaces ICommon {
    public void sayhello();
}

@Stateless
@LocalHome
public class BeanA implements ICommon {

    public void sayhello() {
        // say hallo 
    }

}

@Stateless
@LocalHome
public class BeanB implements ICommon {

    public void sayhello() {
        // say hallo 
    }

}
```

and here the CDI "client" which uses the EJB services

```
@Model
public void MyJSFControllerBean {

    @Inject
    private BeanA beanA;

    @Inject
    private BeanB beanB;

    public String sayhello(final String input) {
        if("a".equals(input)) {
            beanA.sayhello();
        } else {
            beanB.sayhello();
        }

        return "success";
    }

}
```

Or the other solution would be that you create a CDI producer to create this. but then you are mixing two different concepts. but i think it depends ou your concrete usecase.

dynamic injection does not exist! with @Produce and @Qualifier you can control the creation of the required CDI beans to inject. but this is only for CDI not for EJB.

here the CDI producer example:

```
public void ICommonProducer {

    @EJB
    private BeanA beanA;

    @EJB
    private BeanB beanB;

    @Produces
    public ICommon produce() {
        final String input = "?????";
        // but here you have the problem that must get the input from elsewhere....

        if("a".equals(input)) {
            beanA.sayhello();
        } else {
            beanB.sayhello();
        }
    }

}

@Model
public void MyJSFControllerBean {

    @Inject
    private ICommon common;

    public String sayhello(final String input) {
        common.sayhello();
        return "success";
    }

}
```

i have not teseted this code...

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I tried the without producer, but not with inject but @EJB. I hope this should also work. However while deployment, all my beans are deployed but while calling function I am getting noEJB receiver error.I am not understanding why :-( below is my code

Comment: How does @produce help in this? I mean when use "@EJB" proxy object will any way be created and only when method is called on that, container will then create a stateless instance as you said.  I wrote my code exactly the same manner on method  common.sayhello(), in my case I am performing a Jndi lookup from my main method. I am getting error with no EJB receiver, not sure why!!